# Should I avoid using a phrase that is commonly misused?

Tags: phrases, cultural-correctness

The phrase *"Doesn't do nothing"* is often used when a person actually means,  *"Doesn't do anything."*

Should I avoid using this phrase? Generally, I would, but in my context, I want to negate what I had said previously.

Example:

I wrote that clicking a button does nothing. Later on, I found out that it does do something, so I want to write that I was wrong and that it, in fact, *doesn't do nothing* but does x.

Is it okay to write it like this or should I avoid it because people commonly misuse this phrase to mean the opposite?

Comment: I would avoid the phrase.  Unless you intend to be colloquial, in which case the proper phrase is "don't do nuttin'".

Comment: Whereas this is a phrase I would not usually say, I would say it in this context.  You aren't using it in the semantically incorrect way but in the correct way.  "I found out that that button didn't do nothing; it did something, and that something changed everything, changed the world.  The world would never be the same again."

Comment: I appreciate the question but asking if this is "okay" is not really the best way to go about finding information because it's a vague question. Are you asking: 

 - Is it grammatical by standards of English grammar? Yes it is.
 - Is it clear to a native speaker? No, as you implied, it's very likely to be misunderstood.
 - Would each of us advise it? That's an opinion question, but I would not advise it. Clarity in language is a very important value to me. You have to ask yourself what you're trying to accomplish by writing this passage.

Answer (score 3):

The context you supply:

> doesn't do *nothing* but does *x*

makes it clear that you're using the phrase "doesn't do nothing" in the way you intend.

To avoid the problematic construct altogether, you could say something along the lines of:

> Contrary to my previous report, the button isn't passive but instead does *x*.

Answer (score 1):

In English, a double negative is taken literally, so the two negatives cancel each other out.  In some other languages multiple negatives merely add weight to the negation.

Comment: I agree, but if you read the question, the asker actually wants the two to cancel each other out, so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

If you value clarity, @Lawrence has some great suggestions. Here are some more.

> I wrote that clicking a button does nothing. Later on, I found out that it does do something, so I want to write that contrary to my previous report, it does in fact do something.
>
> I wrote that clicking a button does nothing. Later on, I found out that I was wrong, so I want to write explaining my error. [It is not true that the button does nothing; to the contrary, it actually does something.]

The sentence in brackets is clearer than yours but still somewhat wordy. I think it can be omitted without much loss, but if you feel a strong need to assert the falseness of the proposition that the button does nothing, then this would be a much better way to do it.